# CSS - Fill remaining space if it's avaliable

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to create a mosaic of options with images of different sizes, so the free vertical space needs to be filled. Is there any way using CSS or do I need to use JavaScript somehow?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukl8L.jpg

```
<style>
  .options {
    width: 1230px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
  }

  #stream .large {
    width: 400px;
    height: 575px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: white;
  }

  #stream .big {
    width: 400px;
    height: 380px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: white;
  }

  #stream .medium {
    width: 400px;
    height: 185px;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }

  #stream .small {
    width: 195px;
    height: 185px;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really; this is what Javascript libraries like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) were built to do. Masonry is easy to use, you should be able to drop it in and have it arrange your items more tightly.

Comment: What a shame! Thanks!